'No required module provides package' docker compose error
Error While Building Docker Compose!!

[orders 7/7] RUN go build *.go:
0.359 main.go:9:2: no required module provides package github.com/dojeto/order-management-system/common; to add it:
0.359   go get github.com/dojeto/order-management-system/common
0.359 grpc_handler.go:7:2: no required module provides package github.com/dojeto/order-management-system/common/api; to add it:
0.359   go get github.com/dojeto/order-management-system/common/api


failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c go build *.go" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
DockerFile :
FROM golang:1.22

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.mod

COPY go.sum go.sum

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build *.go

ENTRYPOINT [ "./main" ]


Docker Compose File:
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo
    networks:
      - my-network
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./common:/app/common

  orders:
    container_name: orders
    build: 
      context: ./orders
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - my-network
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./common:/app/common

  gateway:
    container_name: gateway
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    build:
      context: ./gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - /home/dojeto/Projects/MicroServices/common:/app/common
      
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata6:


File Structure
Gateway and order service is using common file but as both the service have separate Dockerfile for them unable to locate  common module
how can i fix this issue any suggestion !?
I want to use common folder in both the container so both service can work properly ....


Folder Structure


Is your source tree laid out so that you have gateway and common subdirectories, the application is in gateway, and it's trying to include source files from common?  An image build can't see anything outside the build: { context: } directory, so you need to rearrange this to include the parent directory as the build context.  volumes: aren't used as part of the image build at all, and mounting source code into a Go-based container isn't usually useful.

Thank You For Pointing Out, so what should I do now ? like I have to make one dockerfile in the root directory ? But then how will I able to run all the service containers separately ?
Gateway required a common folder module to perform some task and as docker container scope is limited it's not accessible and go build is getting failed.

Without looking at code it's an assumption, but judging by the symptoms it may be related to differences between your local OS and a variant of Linux, where you build.
E.g. if you are on Win, which is case insensitive, build may fail due to case sensitivity of the Linux. Check that module path has consistent letter case across the whole project.
Module path is what you specified in go.mod after module.
For example:
in go.mod:  module example.com/foo/bAr
in main.go: import example.com/foo/bar

will lead to this error on Linux (thus, during a build in Docker as well).

It seems like there might be an error in building the image, not just starting it. To address this, you should ensure all necessary files are in accessible locations (also the mentioned modules in the error message) and try building your image beforehand.

It is working in my local machine as every module is in the right but whenever I am trying to build in a docker container, It's keep giving me error due to common module is not found and go build not able to build it

Ahh so I maybe understood u wrong ur problem is not building the docker image, it is your docker image not starting up on a different machine?
